# How to ignore or flag stuff outside of environments and commands

Tags: macros

In the preamble of a LaTeX document, commands are processed but everything that would result in output leads to the error `Missing \begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
This leads to an error.
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In a `tikzpicture` environment, everything that cannot be interpreted as a tikz command is ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  Something that is ignored
  \node {A};
  Something that is ignored
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Question:** What is the easiest way to achieve a similar effect, say within a dedicated environment? As an example, the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{IgnoreOrFlagUnknownStuff}{}{}% ??? to be defined
\newenvironment{A}{\paragraph{A:}}{}
\newcommand\B[1]{\paragraph{B:} #1\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{IgnoreOrFlagUnknownStuff}
  Something to ignore or to complain about.
  \begin{A}
    This is OK.
  \end{A}
  Something to ignore or to complain about.
  \B{This is also OK.}
  Something to ignore or to complain about.
\end{IgnoreOrFlagUnknownStuff}
\end{document}
```

should either complain about the `Something to ignore` sentences or ignore them, while processing the rest.

Comment: TikZ actually doesn't ignore the text, but typesets it using `\nullfont`, so nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for `\nullfont`, this was the missing link.

Comment: @egreg I'm still missing something. In my self-answer below, the error via `\everypar` is actually not triggered by the first line where I added the comment, but only by the last line. What's puzzling for me is that in `latex.ltx`, the identical (?) construction `\everypar{... error ...}\nullfont` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Enrico's comments one can suppress the output by switching to the `\nullfont`.

```
\newenvironment{IgnoreUnknownStuff}{\nullfont}{}
```

This will generate warnings like `Missing character: There is no S in font nullfont!` in the log file, which can be suppressed by setting `\tracinglostchars=0`. The ignored stuff may still result in extra vertical and horizontal space, probably because of entering and leaving hmode and adding spaces at the end of lines, so the ignored stuff does not become completely invisible.

To issue an error message for ignored stuff like the LaTeX format does for characters in the preamble, one can use `\everypar` to generate an error when entering hmode by setting `\everypar{\ErrorUnknownStuff}`. One has to make sure that TeX is in vmode whenever ignored characters are to be expected; note the `\par` commands below.

```
\newenvironment{FlagUnknownStuff}%
  {\everypar{\ErrorUnknownStuff}%
   \nullfont
   \par
   \tracinglostchars=0
  }{}
\newcommand\ErrorUnknownStuff{\GenericError{}{Unknown Stuff}{}{}}
% Commands and environments that may appear in the environment
\newenvironment{A}{\normalfont\paragraph{A:}}{\par}
\newcommand\B[1]{{\normalfont\paragraph{B:} #1\par}}
\newcommand\C[1]{{\everypar{}\normalfont #1\par}}
```

`\everypar` has to be reverted by `\everypar{}` before hmode is entered deliberately. In the definitions above `\paragraph` will do this implicitly, but the definition of `\C` has to do it explicitly.

The left image is the result of the code below. An error is issued for each of the four ignore-and-complain-lines in the environment `FlagUnknownStuff`. The image to the right is the output when removing all lines to be ignored; note the differences in spacing.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{IgnoreUnknownStuff}{\nullfont}{}
\newenvironment{FlagUnknownStuff}%
  {\everypar{\ErrorUnknownStuff}%
   \nullfont
   \par
   \tracinglostchars=0
  }{}
\newcommand\ErrorUnknownStuff{\GenericError{}{Unknown Stuff}{}{}}
% Commands and environments that may appear in the environment
\newenvironment{A}{\normalfont\paragraph{A:}}{\par}
\newcommand\B[1]{{\normalfont\paragraph{B:} #1\par}}
\newcommand\C[1]{{\everypar{}\normalfont #1\par}}
\begin{document}
Before.
\begin{IgnoreUnknownStuff}
  Something to ignore.
  \begin{A}
    This is OK.
  \end{A}
  Something to ignore.
  \B{This is also OK.}%
  Something to ignore.
  \C{This also.}
  Something to ignore.
\end{IgnoreUnknownStuff}
In-between.
\begin{FlagUnknownStuff}
  Something to ignore and to complain about.
  \begin{A}
    This is OK.
  \end{A}
  Something to ignore and to complain about.
  \B{This is also OK.}
  Something to ignore and to complain about.
  \C{This also.}
  Something to ignore and to complain about.
\end{FlagUnknownStuff}
After.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to revert to `\everypar{}` as soon as the allowed environments or commands appear. Besides, the first text doesn't start a paragraph.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for the hints. I have revised my solution. Feel free to criticize ... or to provide a better answer yourself ;-)

Comment: You can avoid warnings in the transcript file about nonexistent characters by adding `\tracinglostchars = 0` to the definition of your environments.  For efficiency purposes, I’d also add `\frenchspacing`, as _The TeXbook_ suggests at the end of Appendix D.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thanks for the hint, I already wondered about this. I have added it to my answer for the case when an explicit error message is generated.

Comment: You may also want to disable `\selectfont`